# How to set the color of a substring in a textbox in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, fonts, textbox

I have a piece of code like this :-

```
**mdg.setHTML("This will call @ " +phoneWidget.getLabelText()+" "+ phoneWidget.getTextBoxValue());**
```

Now I need to change the font-color and style of `phoneWidget.getLabelText() and phoneWidget.getTextBoxValue()`

where mdg is a text-box.

How do I do it in GWT ?

Comment: Do you want to set a color to the text in mdg text-box ?

Comment: @Dilantha : Yes and No. No, I don't want to add color to the complete text box, but I want to add color to phoneWidget.getLabelText() and phoneWidget.getTextBoxValue() present within the mdg text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pasting HTML into the dialog, so you can use whatever methods you'd use to set the color of HTML text. I suggest using a [`span` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) around your highlighted values with appropriate CSS